# Monitoring SFTP for any files and create data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, ftp

We currently have a few File Drop triggered automations which monitor a folder in our FTP server, import the file when it's added and populate a data extension.

Is there any way I can set up a folder in the SFTP where I can put files, as above, but instead of updating an existing data extension, it creates a new one, using the filename as the data extension name?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting up the File Drop and using a Script activity to control the creation of the data extension. The draw back is you would still need to add them to a master datension , to act as a staging area , then execute the script to create the new data extension based on the name

Comment: I was thinking this - currently searching for some help writing a 'create data extension' SSJS block. Would it be possible to do File Drop -> Script to Create DE -> Data Import, so I don't have to use a staging area?

Comment: How do you get the name to use in the script?

Comment: I don't think you would be able to use a data import into a DE created in the Script unless you used a naming convention with date/time variables that are available.  The best solution I can think of (which I believe is what @Data_Kid is suggesting) is to import into a holder DE and then use a script to a. create the new DE and then b. create a sql interaction and run it to move this data into the new DE.

Comment: curious - would it be possible to use %%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% as the name, or do we need to hardcode the name in the SSJS?  I'm very new to this kind of thing, so I apologize if it's a dumb question.